# German equivalent for ‘location estimation’

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What is the equivalent for *Touchscreen location estimation* in German? *Location estimation* applies to both Geographic and Electronics.

Is *Touch stelle schätzung* the right one?

Comment: What location is being estimated? A geographical location displayed on a touchscreen ("Lage", "Standort", possibly "Position"), or the location of the finger executing a touch input (rather only "Position", under no circumstances "Standort")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you trial-translation is not German. It is wrong.

**touchscreen**
The noun “touchscreen” is used as english loan word in German: »der Touchscreen« (remember to write nouns *always* with an uppercase first letter in German)

**location**
This is: »die Lage« or »der Standort«.

**estimation**
Can be translated as: »die Schätzung« or »die Abschätzung«. But in this case it is better to use »Die Bestimmung«. This has not exactly the same meaning as the english word, but I still think it fits better in German.
The translation of »die Bestimmung« is »determination«, which literally means, that you find the accurate location, while *estimation* means: make an educated guess.

So I would translate this term as one of these:

> Standortbestimmung mittels Touchscreen
>   touchscreenbasierte Standortbestimmung

If you want to stay closer to the original meaning, you can say:

> Standortschätzung mittels Touchscreen
>   touchscreenbasierte Standortschätzung

But I would prefer the version using »Bestimmung«

Comment: I would also prefer Standortbestimmung. Positionsschätzung might be a slightly more technical version.

Comment: As expressed in [my comment](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25878/german-equivalent-for-location-estimation#comment61547_25878), I am not sure yet the OP is actually looking for "Standort".

Comment: I was looking for the location of finger touch.

Comment: @lerner1225: In that case, this answer is not correct. Why have you accepted it? I'm confused now. In any case, I have added [an answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/25890/5999) that covers the meaning you described for future reference.

Answer (score 7):

As has meanwhile been explained by the OP in a [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25878/german-equivalent-for-location-estimation#comment61567_25879), this question is looking for “the location of finger touch”. In other words, this question is asking for how to call the position at which a touch is registered from a finger.<sup>1</sup>

For this meaning, the words *Standort* and *Ort* are incorrect, in my opinion, as they imply a geographical location. *Lage* is at least misleading, as it could also refer to the orientation of the finger (e.g., perpendicularly towards the touchscreen, or in an angle of 20° over its surface, etc.).

For the described purpose, I suggest *Positionsschätzung*. This word repeatedly appears in related contexts, e.g.:

- [“7.1 Positionsschätzung der Hand vor einem Display”](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/649517/649517.pdf)
- (with respect to touchless gesture input:) [“Mit diesen Daten wird dann eine Positionsschätzung eines Objekts vorgenommen, das sich über dem System befindet.”](http://www.elektroniknet.de/halbleiter/sonstiges/artikel/82359/1/)

Alternatively, the word *Bestimmung* can be used, as suggested in [user unknown’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/25889/5999) and [Hubert’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/25879/5999):

- [“Vielfältige Positionsbestimmung”](http://www.wdr.de/tv/kopfball/sendungsbeitraege/2010/1107/touchscreen.jsp)
- [“Ein kapazitiver Touchscreen funktioniert ohne Druckempfindlichkeit, da die Positionsbestimmung ohne Veränderungen in einem elektrischen Feld erfolgt.”](https://books.google.de/books?id=tO8xBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=touchscreen+positionsbestimmung&source=bl&ots=54w9c7u-e5&sig=Nq3oHQjUcTDGNKYiHEAeNKDRl7c&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCGoVChMI7MzG_O2oyAIVqe5yCh3HKQTO#v=onepage&q=touchscreen%20positionsbestimmung&f=false) (*Betriebssysteme für Smartphones: Android vs. iOS* by Johannes Blischke)
- (with respect to stylus input:) [“Über die einzelnen Antennen wird nacheinander HF-Energie abgestrahlt, das im Nahfeld in den Resonanzkreis des Stiftes eingekoppelt und für die Positionsbestimmung ausgewertet wird.”](http://www.itwissen.info/definition/lexikon/Touchscreen-touchscreen.html)

<sup>1</sup>: Explanation of the underlying problem: When inputting coordinates with a pointing device such as a mouse, a cursor is shown on screen. A particular pixel of that cursor (e.g. the tip of an arrow) is the hotspot, the very pixel that gets selected. On a touchscreen, no such cursor is available; instead, users have to use a much less precise pointing device — their finger (or maybe a stylus, but even a stylus tip is usually larger than a pixel). As a result of that, the touchscreen software has to estimate which location on the touchscreen the user thought they were pointing at — this is the location estimation of a finger on the touchscreen.

Answer (score 1):

**Ortsbestimmung** ist *location estimation*.

Eine *Standortsbestimmung* wäre es, wenn man an dem Punkt wäre, was hier nicht notwendig vorrausgesetzt wird.

*Touchscreen* ist ein gängiges Fremdwort, kann aber als **berührungsempfindlicher Bildschirm** übersetzt werden, wenn man unbedingt will.